# Facebook login event subscribe doesn't work

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-likebox

In my web platform I show a Facebook *likebox* to users.

I need to know when a user log in on Facebook after clicking the **like** button of the likebox.

I tried to do so by using the *FB.Event.subscribe* function on events **auth.statusChange** and **auth.authResponseChange** (suggested in documentation), but without success.

This is an example of the code I use:

```
/* Just to wait facebook functions are ready */
var handle = setInterval(function() {
    if(typeof(FB) != 'undefined'){
        fbReady();
        clearInterval(handle);
    }
}, 1000);

/* Get connection status */
function fbReady() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            status == "connected";
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            status == "not_authorized";
        } else {
            status == "unknown";
        }

        /* I don't use status yet */
        setSubscriptions(status);
    });
}

/* set event listeners for login and liked */
function setSubscriptions(status){
    /* Like event subscription */
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
        function(response) {
            alert('user liked the page');
        });

    /* status change event subscription */
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange',
        function(response) {
            alert('user status is changed in:' + response.status);
        });

    /* auth response change event subscription */
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange',
        function(response) {
            alert('user auth response is changed in:' + response.status);
        });
}
```

Only **edge.create** event fires the related callback when the *like* button is pressed, but nothing happen when a user log in.

The situation does not change if the user which log in has status **connected** (he accepted my App in facebook settings) or **not_authorized**.

I tried to supply a JsFiddle with an interactive code but Facebook js sdk doesn't work that way.

Thanks in advance for your help